# Titration of Na2CO3 against HCl

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, titration

> $\pu{25 mL}$ of $\pu{0.125 M}$ $\ce{Na2CO3}$ is titrated with $\pu{0.100 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$. Given that $K_\mathrm{a1} = 4.3\times 10^{-7}$ and $K_\mathrm{a2} = 4.8\times10^{-11}$ for the diprotic acid $\ce{H2CO3}$, calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$ values of the two equivalence points in the titration.

My method was to assume that all $\ce{CO3^2-}$ initially would be neutralized to form $\ce{HCO3-}$, and from there use the $K_\mathrm{a2}$ value to calculate the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ via equilibrium, but this gives me the wrong answer (by about $3$ $\mathrm{pH}$ units).

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong, and how I should do it correctly? (The correct answer apparently should be $8.34$ for the 1st equivalence point.)

Comment: Use $K_\mathrm{b1}=\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a1}}$ in addition to $K_\mathrm{a2}$ in order to calculate $[\ce{H3O+}]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main confusion you're having here is that you misinterpretted the composition of the system at the first end point.

While you are correct that an equivalent non-equilibrium system is just all $\ce{HCO3-}$, it is not correct to think of this as an acid. This is bicarbonate. If you take sodium bicarbonate and dissolve it water, it is *basic*, not acidic. Therefore, you should have converted your $K_{\mathrm{a1}}$ value into a $K_{\mathrm{b}}$ value and treated the system as a base instead.

The second equivalence point is when you have the equivalent concentration of $\ce{H2CO3}$. Treat this as a normal acid dissociation problem.

Answer (score 1):

At the first equivalence point:
$$\ce{Na_2CO_3 +HCl ->NaHCO_3 + NaCl}$$
$$\text{moles of}~ \ce{Na_2CO_3} =25\times{0.125}\times{10^{-3}}=3.125\times{10^{-3}}\pu{mol}=\text{moles of}~ \ce{HCl}=\text{moles of}~\ce{NaHCO3} $$
$$\text{moles of}~ \ce{HCl} =3.125\times{10^{-3}}=\pu{V_\ce{HCl}\times{0.1}} $$
$$\pu{V_\ce{HCl}}=31.25\times{10^{-3}}$$
$$\text{Total volume}=25\times{10^{-3}}+31.25\times{10^{-3}}=56.25\times{10^{-3}}~\pu{L}$$
$$[\ce{NaHCO3}]=\frac{3.125\times{10^{-3}}\pu{mol}}{56.25\times{10^{-3}}~\pu{L}}=5.6\times{10^{-2}}\pu{M}=\ce[{HCO_3^-}]$$
$$[\ce{H_3O^+}]=\sqrt\frac{K_\mathrm{a1}K_\mathrm{a2}[\ce{NaHCO_3}]+K_\mathrm{a1}K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a1}+[\ce{NaHCO_3}]}$$

$$[\ce{H_3O^+}]=\sqrt\frac{(4\cdot{3}\times{10^{-7}}\times{4\cdot{8}\times{10^{-11}}}\times{0.056})+(4\cdot{3}\times{10^{-7}}\times{10^{-14}})}{(4\cdot{3}\times{10^{-7}}+0.056)}\approx{5.35\times{10^{-9}}}\pu~{M}$$
$$\pu{pH}={8.27}\approx{8.3}$$

Answer (score 1):

At the second equivalence point:
$$\ce{Na_2CO_3 +2HCl ->H_2CO_3 + 2NaCl}$$
$$\text{moles of}~ \ce{Na_2CO_3} =25\times{0.125}\times{10^{-3}}=3.125\times{10^{-3}}\pu{mol}=\text{moles of}~\ce{H_2CO3} $$
$$\text{moles of}~ \ce{HCl} =2\times{3.125\times{10^{-3}}}=\pu{V_\ce{HCl}\times{0.1}} $$
$$\pu{V_\ce{HCl}}=62.25\times{10^{-3}}$$
$$\text{Total volume}=25\times{10^{-3}}+62.25\times{10^{-3}}=87.25\times{10^{-3}}~\pu{L}$$
$$[\ce{H_2CO3}]=\frac{3.125\times{10^{-3}}\pu{mol}}{87.25\times{10^{-3}}~\pu{L}}=3.58\times{10^{-2}}\pu{M}$$
Treat carbonic acid solutions as if $\ce{H2CO3}$ were monoprotic, because the first
acid dissociation constant is much greater than either$ K_\mathrm{a2}$ or $ K_\mathrm{w}$  , so this becomes a standard monoprotic weak acid problem:

$$ K_\mathrm{a1} = 4.3\times{10^{–7}} =\frac{[\ce{H^+}][\ce{HCO_3^− }]}{[\ce{H_2CO_3}]}$$
Assume : $ [\ce{H+}] = [\ce{HCO_3^-} ]$ , the equilibrium expression becomes:
$$K_\mathrm{a1} = 4.3\times{10^{–7}} =\frac{[\ce{H^+}]^2}{0.0358-[\ce{H+}] }$$
As: $0.0358 >> K_\mathrm{a1}$,justifies the further approximation of dropping the $ [\ce{H+}]$ term in the denominator.
$$ K_\mathrm{a1} =4.3\times{10^{-7}} =\frac{[\ce{H^+}]^2}{0.0358}$$
$$[\ce{H^+}]=1.24\times{10^{-4}}\pu{M}$$
$$\pu{pH}=3.92$$

Answer (score 0):

$pK_{a1} = -\log{(4.3\times10^{-7})} = 6.3665$

$pK_{a2} = -\log{(4.8\times10^{-11})} = 10.3188$

eq. pt. $ = \dfrac{6.3665+10.3188}{2} = 8.34265 \ce{->[Rounding]} 8.34$

Comment: but why does this work? also this cant be extended to calculate the second equivalence point

Comment: At eq. pt $\ce{[H2CO3] = [CO3^{2-}]}$. // What would you average with 6.3665 to get second eq. pt?!?

Comment: This relationship is also reasonably easy to derive using the corresponding Henderson-Hasselbalch equations, if you've learned though already.

Comment: At second eq. pt. (for $K_{a1}$) $\ce{[H+] = [HCO3-]}$. I'll leave the math to you.

Comment: $$\pu{pH}=\frac{1}{2}\times{(pK_\mathrm{a1}+pK_\mathrm{a2} )}$$


THis foumula suitable when $K_\mathrm{a1}<<[\ce{HCO_3^-}]\text{with concentrated solution,but neglegt water autoionization and assume} [\ce{H2CO3}] = [\ce{CO3-} ]$